# Headerdoc, Objective-C, anonymous type, ERROR

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, anonymous-types, headerdoc

I have to generate a doc for Xcode's project Objective-C.
I have an error `anonymous type`. I think headerdoc doesn't like @interface section. Can someone resolve that?

My apologies for some grammar mistakes, I have a Xcode's project Objective-C, I want generate a doc with a script (I'm not at my work so I will try explain the problem). In my project I have a class x

.h

```
/*! headerdoc comment */
@interface x: NSObject
@end
```

.m

```
#import x.h
@interface x(){
  /*! headerdoc comment */
  NSString *_xID;
}
@end

@implementation x
/*! headerdoc comment */
-(void)aMethod{
}
@end
```

And when I run, I have an error "anonymous type", and when I removed @interface section in .m it's working.

Comment: you need to provide more information, if you want to get helped!